# Filter table with data-id parameters on td

Tags: jquery, html-table

I tried to create a filter table with jquery, the problem here is I want to take a filter in the `data-id` value of a `<td>`.

So when I select an option with the value Yes = 1, it will go to filter field `<th>Option A</th>` which has the parameter `data-id="1"`.

Example HTML

```
<select id="choice" class="form-control select2" >
    <option value="all">choice answer</option>
    <option value="1">Yes</option>
    <option value="2">No</option>
</select>

<table id="dt-answer"  width="100%" cellspacing="2">            
<thead>
    <tr class="headings">
        <th>No</th>
        <th>Question</th>
        <th>Answer</th>
        <th>Option A</th>
        <th>Option B</th>
    </tr>
</thead>                                      
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Question A</td>
        <td data-id="1">Yes</td>
        <td>Yes</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Question B</td>
        <td data-id="2">No</td>
        <td>Yes</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Question C</td>
        <td data-id="2">No</td>
        <td>No</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>Question C</td>
        <td data-id="1">Yes</td>
        <td>No</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>Question D</td>
        <td data-id="2">No</td>
        <td>No</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

jquery

```
$('#choice').change(function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#dt-answer tr").filter(function() {
        $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
})
```

Comment: Also: don't use the w3schools page for `.filter` - it's confusing as it's using it as an `.each` - `.filter` returns the filtered collection to be actioned on after, which the example does not (https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_filters.asp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keeping the `.each` (where `.fitler` was used) - change your jquery to:

```
$('#choice').change(function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#dt-answer tr").each(function() {
        $(this).toggle($(this).find(">td[data-id]").data("id") == value > -1)
    });
})
```

Inside the `.toggle`:

`.find` look for descendants (of `this` which is the `tr`) that match
`">td[data-id]"` direct descendants that are `td` and have a data-id
`.data("id")` get the id and compare with `value`

there are various alternatives to

```
.find(">td[data-id]")
```

eg using `.children()` or `td:eq(2)` for 3rd column.

---

In this case, there's no need for `.each` (/ `.filter`) and changing many DOM elements in a loop may cause your application to appear slugish.  You can use:

```
$('#choice').change(function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#dt-answer tr").hide().has(">td[data-id=" + value + "]").show();
})
```

Comment: it runs but when I want to restore the original data or all it doesn't work

Comment: You'll need to add a clause for that, eg check `if ($(this).val() == "") $("#dt-answer tr").show(); else { ..code as above .. }`

Comment: yes I just thought about it and just finished I added a new data-all to do the original return, thank you for your help

Comment: one more I use your second answer, but how do I follow so that the sequence number also changes <th> No </ th>, ex 2,3,5 to be ex 1,2,3